# How to created nested columns in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to created nested columns within the bootstrap nav. I've tried everything. But it seems like only containers possess this sort of functionality. How can I do this inside a bootstrap nav. Attached is an image of how I want things to be and the current code that I have (which currently has alignment issues).

```
<nav class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
      <img src="images/nexletol-logo.png" alt="NEXLETOL™ (bempedoic acid) tablets" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="images/nexletol-logo.png" alt="NEXLETOL™ (bempedoic acid) tablets" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <ul class="row navbar-nav col-12 col-md-8">
      <li class="nav-item col-4">hello</li>
      <li class="nav-item col-4">hello</li>
      <li class="nav-item col-4">hello</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[nav mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LraIX.png)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this, The image you tag in your question i am doing this code for that only. Check and tell me you want the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <img src="images/nexletol-logo.png" alt="NEXLETOL™ (bempedoic acid) tablets" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <img src="images/nexletol-logo.png" alt="NEXLETOL™ (bempedoic acid) tablets" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <p class="text-center"> Hello </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
       <p class="text-center"> Hello </p>
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
       <p class="text-center"> Hello </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```